# Why reverse routing has been added in play framework?

Tags: playframework

Why reverse routing has been added in play framework since we could have directly called any action method from any other action method?

Comment: what have to tried yet?

Comment: If we want to call any other action method from an action method we have to redirect it to its corresponding url using reverse routing but we could have directly called that method like we do in simple java codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse routing simplifies support of URL endpoints.

Assume we have a route file

```
POST   /login/action          controllers.LoginController.login
```

For example, you create a login page and you need to put an action on the form:

```
<form action="/login/action" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Reverse routing allow you to put here just a method call

```
<form action="@routes.LoginController.login" method="post">
...
</form>
```

In the second case, you will not need to edit the template file if you change the login URL in the `routes` file.

One more thing - in the first case, you can forget to change URL in a template and then, you will end up with a nasty issue when you build is correct, but you have links that end ups with 404.

Comment: I have one more thing to ask i.e."is it same to use redirect in place of reverse routing since in the end everything is a call for both cases?"

Comment: Redirect and reverse routing are different. Redirect: `Redirect("/hello/bob")`. Reverse routing: `routes.Application.hello("Bob")`. Redirect with reverse routing: `Redirect(routes.Application.hello("Bob"))`